# Gorm many to many find with condition

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

[image]

There are simply 3 such entities. My goal is to find resources using gorm. But I want to find it based on a certain condition. Exactly what I want is to find the resources containing the specific word in the name of the service. How should I use a preload and where()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The SO community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues. Sounds like you want all `resources` required by a specific service, but that is not clear. Also what specifically, in this case, is a *preload*.